# Raspberry Pi as a transparent proxy

Tags: networking, bridge

We have a ntlm proxy and I need to connect some IOT devices to the network.

Is it possible to have a raspberry pi with cntlm installed and configured on eth0 to port 3128 then bridge to a USB ethernet adapter (eth1) which will be connected to a GLi.net wireless router. Idea is that the router will connect to the devices but the raspberry pi will hand the proxy authentication.

Will this work? I know how to bridge but how do Inforce the bridge to port 3128 for cntlm?

Comment: What is cntlm ?

Comment: http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The link would be better in the question, not in a comment. You should [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/108040/edit) the question.